# Dynamically adding attributes using Thymeleaf th:attr and th:attrappend

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I want to add ***selected*** to HTML tag **option** using Thymeleaf dynamically by checking the condition of RequestParam:

```
<option value="en" th:text="${#httpServletRequest.getParameter('lang') == null || #httpServletRequest.getParameter('lang') == 'en'} ? #{lang.eng}"></option>
                        <option value="ru"  th:text="#{lang.ru}" th:attr="${#httpServletRequest.getParameter('lang') == 'ru'} ? 'selected' : null"></option>
```

*But I have an error on the second option.*

The reason for doing it because when I switch to another language the selected lang doesn't changing
How I can solve this problem? Or I have to use another approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `selected` attribute you should refer to [Fixed value boolean attributes.](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#fixed-value-boolean-attributes)

That means instead of

```
th:attr="${#httpServletRequest.getParameter('lang') == 'ru'} ? 'selected' : null"
```

you can do:

```
th:selected="${#httpServletRequest.getParameter('lang') == 'ru'}"
```

Comment: Yeah, got it. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer solve your problem, please accept it :)